# Python factorization

Tags: python, algorithm

I'd just like to know the best way of listing all integer factors of a number, given a dictionary of its prime factors and their exponents.
For example if we have {2:3, 3:2, 5:1}  (2^3 * 3^2 * 5 = 360)
Then I could write:

```
for i in range(4):
  for j in range(3):
    for k in range(1):
      print 2**i * 3**j * 5**k
```

But here I've got 3 horrible for loops. Is it possible to abstract this into a function given any factorization as a dictionary object argument?

Comment: My math is rusty, what is the principle that lets you derive all factors from the prime factors?

Comment: That would probably stem from the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, since any non-prime factors have a unique prime factorization that is contained in the prime factorization of the larger number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fast prime factorization module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643647/fast-prime-factorization-module)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, not only you have 3 loops, but this approach won't work if you have more than 3 factors :)

One possible way:

```
def genfactors(fdict):    
    factors = set([1])

    for factor, count in fdict.iteritems():
        for ignore in range(count):
            factors.update([n*factor for n in factors])
            # that line could also be:
            # factors.update(map(lambda e: e*factor, factors))

    return factors

factors = {2:3, 3:2, 5:1}

for factor in genfactors(factors):
    print factor
```

Also, you can avoid duplicating some work in the inner loop: if your working set is (1,3), and want to apply to 2^3 factors, we were doing:

- `(1,3) U (1,3)*2 = (1,2,3,6)`
- `(1,2,3,6) U (1,2,3,6)*2 = (1,2,3,4,6,12)`
- `(1,2,3,4,6,12)  U (1,2,3,4,6,12)*2 = (1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24)`

See how many duplicates we have in the second sets?

But we can do instead:

- `(1,3) + (1,3)*2 = (1,2,3,6)`
- `(1,2,3,6) + ((1,3)*2)*2 = (1,2,3,4,6,12)`
- `(1,2,3,4,6,12) + (((1,3)*2)*2)*2 = (1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24)`

The solution looks even nicer without the sets:

```
def genfactors(fdict):
    factors = [1]

    for factor, count in fdict.iteritems():
        newfactors = factors
        for ignore in range(count):
            newfactors = map(lambda e: e*factor, newfactors)
            factors += newfactors

    return factors
```

Comment: +1, This is one of nicer solutions as it shows that you're taking the cartesian product of [r_0], [r_1] by multiplying the product by each new set.

Answer (score 15):

I have [blogged about this](http://numericalrecipes.wordpress.com/tag/divisors/), and the fastest pure python (without itertools) comes from a post by Tim Peters to the python list, and uses nested recursive generators:

```
def divisors(factors) :
    """
    Generates all divisors, unordered, from the prime factorization.
    """
    ps = sorted(set(factors))
    omega = len(ps)

    def rec_gen(n = 0) :
        if n == omega :
            yield 1
        else :
            pows = [1]
            for j in xrange(factors.count(ps[n])) :
                pows += [pows[-1] * ps[n]]
            for q in rec_gen(n + 1) :
                for p in pows :
                    yield p * q

    for p in rec_gen() :
        yield p
```

Note that the way it is written, it takes a list of prime factors, not a dictionary, i.e. `[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5]` instead of `{2 : 3, 3 : 2, 5 : 1}`.

Comment: Wow, the speed of this is incredible!

Comment: It really is fast... I spent some time trying to give it a 'personal touch', and ended up coming to the conclusion that even renaming the variables affected speed negatively!!! ;-)

Answer (score 11):

Using [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from Python 2.6:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import itertools, operator

def all_factors(prime_dict):
    series = [[p**e for e in range(maxe+1)] for p, maxe in prime_dict.items()]
    for multipliers in itertools.product(*series):
        yield reduce(operator.mul, multipliers)
```

Example:

```
print sorted(all_factors({2:3, 3:2, 5:1}))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 24, 30, 36, 40, 45, 60,
 72, 90, 120, 180, 360]
```

Comment: you want operator.mul here, not operator.prod :)

Comment: This is really nice, but I don't like that it relies on some new function in Python 2.6

Comment: @Christwo: The documentation for itertools.product (see the link I provided above) contains pure Python implementation of the `product()`. It is just 6 line of code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  When you've got an algorithm that needs n nested for loops, you can usually turn it into a recursive function:

```
def print_factors(d, product=1):
    if len(d) == 0:      # Base case: we've dealt with all prime factors, so
        print product    # Just print the product
        return
    d2 = dict(d)         # Copy the dict because we don't want to modify it
    k,v = d2.popitem()   # Pick any k**v pair from it
    for i in range(v+1): # For all possible powers i of k from 0 to v (inclusive)
                         # Multiply the product by k**i and recurse.
        print_factors(d2, product*k**i)

d = {2:3, 3:2, 5:1}
print_factors(d)
```

Comment: eeek. O(nfactor*factordepth) calls: O(nfactor*factordepth) dicts ? :(

Comment: Yes; I had a version with that but it was uglier and less effective at demonstrating the general idea, which is recursive looping.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you have here is a set, consisting of each factor of the target number.  In your example, the set would be `{2 2 2 3 3 5}`.  Each strict subset of that set is the factorization of one of the divisors of your number, so if you can generate all the subsets of that set, you can multiply the elements of each subset together and get all the integer divisors.

The code should be pretty obvious from there: generate a list containing the factorization, generate all subsets of that list (bonus points for using a generator; I think there's a relevant function in the standard library).  Then multiply and go from there.  Not optimally efficient by any means, but nice looking.