# optimization help to find max number of divisors

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve problem 12 of Euler project. What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors? ( the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28). This is my code, but it is not fast enough..
Do you have any optimization tips?

```
n=0
a=0
list=[]
maxcount=0


while True:
    n+=1
    a+=n
    count=0
    for x in range(1,int(a+1)):
        if a%x==0:
            count+=1   
            if count>maxcount:
                maxcount=count
                print a, "has", maxcount, "dividors"
```

Thank you!

Comment: only check divisors up to the sqrt of the number. Saves millions of checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with reducing the search space, no need to look at numbers that are not triangle numbers.  Also try looking at divisors in `range(1, sqrt(n))` instead of `range(1, n)`

Answer (score 1):

Grab the code from this question which implements very fast prime factorization:
[Fast prime factorization module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643647/fast-prime-factorization-module)

Then use the answer to this question to convert your prime factors into a list of all divisors (the length is what you want):
[What is the best way to get all the divisors of a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171765/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-all-the-divisors-of-a-number)

For example, you can add the following function (adapted from the second link) to the bottom of the module from the first link:

```
def alldivisors(n):
    factors = list(factorization(n).items())
    nfactors = len(factors)
    f = [0] * nfactors
    while True:
        yield reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [factors[x][0]**f[x] for x in range(nfactors)], 1)
        i = 0
        while True:
            if i >= nfactors:
                return
            f[i] += 1
            if f[i] <= factors[i][1]:
                break
            f[i] = 0
            i += 1
```

Then in your code to count divisors you would use `len(list(alldivisors(a)))` which will calculate the number of divisors significantly more quickly than the brute force method you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from number theory: try caching, and doing things the other way around. For example: When you already know that 300 has 18 divisors (and what they are), what does that mean for a number which is dividable by 300? Can you cache such information? (sure you can.)

Pure python speedup hacks won't help you, you need a better algorithm.