# Python Repeated Sampling Without Replacement from a Given List

Tags: python, sampling

given a list of (e.g.) integers, I would like to sample `n` elements without replacement, remove the sampled items from the original list and repeat this process until now elements in the original list remains. Returning a list of `round(len(list)/n)`.

I know about [`random.sample()`](https://pynative.com/python-random-sample/), however I didnt find a implementation for repeated sampling without replacement. My pseudo code below is missing the removement of the sampled elements from the original list. However while I am writing this function I am wondering if there isnt something like this already implemented or a more elegant solution to this?

**Pseudo-Code**

```
def repeated_sample_without_replacement(my_list, n):
    # where n = number of samples,
    k = int(len(my_list) / n)
    if len(my_list)%n != 0:
        samples = np.repeat(n,k)
        samples = np.append(samples, len(my_list) % n)
    else:
        samples = np.repeat(n,k)
    k = len(my_list) / n
    out = []
    for s in samples:
        out.append(random.sample(my_list, s))
        # remove the now sample elements from my_list
    
    return out

x = repeated_sample_without_replacement(ids,10)
print(x)
```

**Example Data**

```
# Sample Data
ids_clean = [*range(1,40)]
In[71]: # Remove Some ID to Better Represent my Purpose
ids = ids_clean[:12] + ids_clean[13:26] + ids_clean[27:]
ids
Out[73]: 
[1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
 5,
 6,
 7,
 8,
 9,
 10,
 11,
 12,
 14,
 15,
 16,
 17,
 18,
 19,
 20,
 21,
 22,
 23,
 24,
 25,
 26,
 28,
 29,
 30,
 31,
 32,
 33,
 34,
 35,
 36,
 37,
 38,
 39]
len(ids)
Out[74]: 37
```

**Desired Output**

```
[[1,4,5,6..],[2,8,9,...],[13,15,16,...][27,10,..]]
```

Comment: Python is so close to pseudocode that the pseudocode you wrote there is actually valid python ;)

Comment: Initially I wanted to write pseudo :D however I switch to python as what I wrote was already pretty close to it

Comment: Btw. It is not a duplicate. The linked answer is 7 years ago and not easily adopted in Pythom 3. I Tried, and way to complicated if you compare to the correctly provided answere here

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean with "not easily adopted in Pythom 3"?

Comment: @BjörnB It's not an *exact* duplicate, but [Tim Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18921596/984421) essentially gives the same solution as you got here. The main difference is in how to split the randomised list into `n` chunks, which is dealt with in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24483182/984421).

Comment: @superbrain The answer provided in the alleged duplicate (as well as many others) are working with a generator (`yield`). Their usage example `gen.next()` gives me the error `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'` beyond the typical py2 py3 shaningans (like `print "abc"` need to be `print("abc")`). I just found out about the dunder method `.__next()__` or `next(gen)`. However I don't think it hurts that there is a shorter and better python 3 solution visible in this thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code shows that you're overall trying to sample the entire given list. So just `random.shuffle` it once and then split it into chunks. Or even just slices with step `n`, which makes it easier:

```
from random import shuffle

def repeated_sample_without_replacement(my_list, n):
    shuffle(my_list)
    return [my_list[i::n] for i in range(n)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> repeated_sample_without_replacement(list(range(10)), 3)
[[7, 5, 0, 1], [2, 6, 8], [4, 3, 9]]
```

Note that this actually produces exactly `n` samples. Not more or less like yours.

Demo of **yours**:

```
>>> repeated_sample_without_replacement(list(range(10)), 3)
[[3, 0, 2], [5, 4, 6], [6, 1, 7], [3]]
>>> repeated_sample_without_replacement(list(range(10)), 13)
[[1, 0, 3, 7, 8, 2, 5, 4, 9, 6]]
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Its exactly what I searched and a really elegant solution!