# Get a new randomized number in python

Tags: python, loops, random, python-itertools

maybe this is a rookie question, but how can i get a new random number everytime it repeats?

```py
realport = random.randint(portstarts, portends)

liste = list(itertools.repeat('{}:{}:{}:{}'.format(hostname, realport, username, password), amount))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "repeats?" Is repetition described as consecutive random numbers with the same value, or just any two equal random numbers regardless of their positions in the sequence?

Comment: At the moment Two or more equal random numbers, but I need consecutive random numbers in the list :)

Comment: Is there some reason you need `itertools.repeat`? Because by definition, `itertools.repeat` always returns the *same* object (not a copy, not a newly created object, literally the exact same object you passed as the first argument to `repeat`).

Comment: Actually I don’t need itertools.repeat, but that was the first solution that came up to my head, then i later tried to add random, so yes I might need a new solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as ShadowRanger commented, `itertools.repeat` probably isn't what you want.

A "[list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34835951/1358308)" might be a nicer way of expressing what you want:

```
def getport():
    return random.randint(portstarts, portends)

liste = [
  '{}:{}:{}:{}'.format(hostname, getport(), username, password)
  for _ in range(amount)
]
```

if you want all of the ports to be unique, then you could instead use `random.sample` to "sample without replacement":

```
liste = [
  '{}:{}:{}:{}'.format(hostname, port, username, password)
  for port in random.sample(range(portstarts, portends+1), amount)
]
```

see, e.g. [How to incrementally sample without replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18921302/1358308) for various ways to sample without replacement in Python