# Finding prime factors logic error python

Tags: python, primes

Not sure why trying to find prime factors like this doesn't work:

```
primes= [2,3,5]
maximum = int(input("Highest number checked: "))
x = 2
prime = False
while x < maximum:
    y = len(primes)
    for n in range(2,y):
        if x % int(primes[n]) == 0:
            prime = True
        else:
            prime = False
            break
    if prime == True:
        primes.append(x)
    x = x+1

print(primes)
```

Inputting 30 prints 2,3,5,5,10,20

Comment: Would you like to share the error message such that we can look into the problem or are you just using this site as your personal journal?

Comment: I just assumed someone would be able to spot my error, sorry?

Comment: Well, someone (probably) already did, but it would be way easier if you gave us the complete error message. 'bool error' says nothing.

Comment: The issue is not resolved and I edited it pal

Comment: When I read your code I find I'm unsure of what your program is *supposed* to do. You seem to have predefined a tiny list of primes. Are those the only ones you are going to check for? That means you can only factor very small numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In this line `if x % int(prime[n]) == 0:` change `prime` to `primes`.

Comment: even with this change the program doesn't work, I inputted 30 and got back 2,3,5,5,10,20

Comment: prime i bool variable and not list. but you write prime[n]. it is not correct

Comment: what is your problem? please explain complete

Comment: When I execute the program, if I input the maximum as 30, it should give me back a list of primes but it gives me back 2,3,5,5,10,20 which is of course wrong so I must have  logic error

Comment: it's meant to give prime factors so of 30 would be 2,3,5

Comment: please check this page for find your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996217/prime-factorization-list

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure why trying to find prime factors like this doesn't work

It doesn't work because you didn't write a (broken) *prime factor finding* program, you wrote a (broken) *prime finding* program.  If we fix it and clean it up, this should be a bit more obvious:

```
primes = [2, 3, 5]

maximum = int(input("Highest number checked: "))

x = 2

while x <= maximum:
    is_prime = True

    for prime in primes:
        if prime * prime > x:
            break

        if x % prime == 0:
            is_prime = False
            break

    if is_prime:
        primes.append(x)

    x = x + 1

print(primes)
```

**USAGE**

```
% python3 test.py
Highest number checked: 100
[2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
%
```

This can be used as part of a *prime factor finding* program, but isn't sufficient on its own.  You need to work through some subset of the list of primes up to N seeing which primes are factors of N.  Not substantially more code than you have now.