# Efficient logic to pad tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to pad a tensor of some shape such that the total memory used by the tensor is always a multiple of 512
E.g.
Tensor shape 16x1x1x4 of type SI32 (Multiply by 4 to get total size)

```
The total elements are 16x4x1x1 = 64
Total Memory required 64x**4** = 256 (Not multiple of 512)
Padded shape would be 32x1x1x4 = 512
```

The below logic works for the basic shape but breaks with a shape e.g. `16x51x1x4 SI32` or something random say `80x240x1x1 U8`
The padding logic goes like below

```
from functools import reduce

DATA_TYPE_MULTIPLYER = 2 # This would change at runtime with different type e.g. 8 with U8 16 with F16 32 with SI32

ALIGNMENT = 512 #Always Constant
CHAR_BIT = 8    # Always Const for given fixed Arch

def approachOne(tensor):
    totalElements = reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), tensor)
    totalMemory = totalElements * DATA_TYPE_MULTIPLYER
    
    divisor = tensor[1] * tensor[2] * tensor[3]
    tempDimToPad = totalElements/divisor
    orgDimToPad = totalElements/divisor
    while (True):
        if ((tempDimToPad * divisor * DATA_TYPE_MULTIPLYER) % ALIGNMENT == 0):
            return int(tempDimToPad - orgDimToPad)
        tempDimToPad = tempDimToPad + 1;
    
def getPadding(tensor):
    totalElements = reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), tensor)
    totalMemory = totalElements * DATA_TYPE_MULTIPLYER
    newSize = totalMemory + (ALIGNMENT - (totalMemory % ALIGNMENT))
    newTotalElements = (newSize * CHAR_BIT) / (CHAR_BIT * DATA_TYPE_MULTIPLYER)
    
    # Any DIM can be padded, using first for now
    paddingValue = tensor[0] 
    padding =  int(((newTotalElements * paddingValue) / totalElements) - paddingValue)
    return padding
    
tensor = [11, 7, 3, 5]
print(getPadding(tensor))
print(approachOne(tensor))
```

`tensorflow` package may help here but I'm originally coding in C++ so just posting in python with a minimal working example
Any help is appreciated, thanks

**Approach 1**
the brute force approach is to keep on incrementing across any chosen dimension by 1 and check if the totalMemory is multiple of 512. The brute force approach works but doesn't give the minimal padding and bloats the tensor

**Updating the conditions**
Initially the approach was to pad across the first dim. Since always padding the first dimension my not be the best solution, just getting rid of this constraint

Comment: You’d need exactly 128 integers in your tensor to have 512 bytes (assuming four bytes for an integer), so the idea is to pad all tensors with fewer integers to that numbers. But the examples for non-working cases you give already have more than 128 integers in the tensors, so you cannot pad them up to reach that number.

Comment: @Schnitte It needs to be multiple of 512. So if e.g the totalMemory required is 800 the padding should be such that the totalMemory is adjusted to 1024

Comment: @CMouse What are the constraints? Can we pad only one dimension or any number of dimensions? Does the result always have to be the minimum size that is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the total memory to be a multiple of `512` then the number of elements in the tensor must be a multiple of `512 // DATA_TYPE_MULTIPLIER`, e.g. `128` in your case. Whatever that number is, it will have a prime factorization of the form `2**n`. The number of elements in the tensor is given by `s[0]*s[1]*...*s[d-1]` where `s` is a sequence containing the shape of the tensor and `d` is an integer, the number of dimensions. The product `s[0]*s[1]*...*s[d-1]` also has some prime factorization and it is a multiple of `2**n` if and only if it contains these prime factors. I.e. the task is to pad the individual dimensions `s[i]` such that the resulting prime factorization of the product `s[0]*s[1]*...*s[d-1]` contains `2**n`.

If the goal is to reach a minimum possible size of the padded tensor, then one can simply iterate through all multiples of the given target number of elements to find the first one that can be satisfied by padding (increasing) the individual dimensions of the tensor <sup>(1)</sup>. A dimension must be increased as long as it contains at least one prime factor that is not contained in the target multiple size. After all dimensions have been increased such that their prime factors are contained in the target multiple size, one can check the resulting size of the candidate shape: if it matches the target multiple size we are done; if its prime factors are a strict subset of the target multiple prime factors, we can add the missing prime factors to any of the dimensions (e.g. the first); otherwise, we can use the excess prime factors to store the candidate shape for a future (larger) multiplier. The first such future multiplier then marks an upper boundary for the iteration over all possible multipliers, i.e. the algorithm will terminate. However, if the candidate shape (after adjusting all the dimensions) has an excess of prime factors w.r.t. the target multiple size as well as misses some other prime factors, the only way is to iterate over all possible padded shapes with size bound by the target multiple size.

The following is an example implementation:

```py
from collections import Counter
import itertools as it
import math
from typing import Iterator, Sequence


def pad(shape: Sequence[int], target: int) -> tuple[int,...]:
    """Pad the given `shape` such that the total number of elements
       is a multiple of the given `target`.
    """
    size = math.prod(shape)
    if size % target == 0:
        return tuple(shape)

    target_prime_factors = get_prime_factors(target)

    solutions: dict[int, tuple[int,...]] = {}  # maps `target` multipliers to corresponding padded shapes

    for multiplier in it.count(math.ceil(size / target)):

        if multiplier in solutions:
            return solutions[multiplier]

        prime_factors = [*get_prime_factors(multiplier), *target_prime_factors]
        
        def good(x):
            return all(f in prime_factors for f in get_prime_factors(x))

        candidate = list(shape)
        for i, x in enumerate(candidate):
            while not good(x):
                x += 1
            candidate[i] = x

        if math.prod(candidate) == multiplier*target:
            return tuple(candidate)

        candidate_prime_factor_counts = Counter(f for x in candidate for f in get_prime_factors(x))
        target_prime_factor_counts = Counter(prime_factors)

        missing = target_prime_factor_counts - candidate_prime_factor_counts
        excess = candidate_prime_factor_counts - target_prime_factor_counts

        if not excess:
            return (
                candidate[0] * math.prod(k**v for k, v in missing.items()),
                *candidate[1:],
            )
        elif not missing:
            solutions[multiplier * math.prod(k**v for k, v in excess.items())] = tuple(candidate)
        else:
            for padded_shape in generate_all_padded_shapes(shape, bound=multiplier*target):
                padded_size = math.prod(padded_shape)
                if padded_size == multiplier*target:
                    return padded_shape
                elif padded_size % target == 0:
                    solutions[padded_size // target] = padded_shape


def generate_all_padded_shapes(shape: Sequence[int], *, bound: int) -> Iterator[tuple[int,...]]:
    head, *tail = shape
    if bound % head == 0:
        max_value = bound // math.prod(tail)
    else:
        max_value = math.floor(bound / math.prod(tail))
    for x in range(head, max_value+1):
        if tail:
            yield from ((x, *other) for other in generate_all_padded_shapes(tail, bound=math.floor(bound/x)))
        else:
            yield (x,)


def get_prime_factors(n: int) -> list[int]:
    """From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16996439/3767239
       Replace with your favorite prime factorization method.
    """
    primfac = []
    d = 2
    while d*d <= n:
        while (n % d) == 0:
            primfac.append(d)  # supposing you want multiple factors repeated
            n //= d
        d += 1
    if n > 1:
       primfac.append(n)
    return primfac
```

Here are a few examples:

```py
pad((16, 1, 1), 128) = (128, 1, 1)
pad((16, 51, 1, 4), 128) = (16, 52, 1, 4)
pad((80, 240, 1, 1), 128) = (80, 240, 1, 1)
pad((3, 5, 7, 11), 128) = (3, 5, 8, 16)
pad((3, 3, 3, 1), 128) = (8, 4, 4, 1)
pad((7, 7, 7, 7), 128) = (7, 8, 8, 8)
pad((9, 9, 9, 9), 128) = (10, 10, 10, 16)
```

---

<sub>**Footnotes:**</sub>
<sub>(1) In fact, we need to find the roots of the polynomial `(s[0]+x[0])*(s[1]+x[1])*...*(s[d-1]+x[d-1]) - multiple*target` for `x[i] >= 0` over the domain of integers. However, I am not aware of any algorithm to solve this problem.</sub>

Comment: Nice approach, the footnote points to an interesting potential rabbit hole too...

Comment: Thankyou! I started a bounty again for the reward!