# Integer factorization in python

Tags: python

I've seen on this website many way of doing integer factorizations in python, but didn't really understand them, so I tried to do it on my own way :

```
def factorisation(n):
fact = []
i = 2
while i<=n:     
    if n%i==0:      
        fact.append(i)
        n//= i
    else:
        i+=1
return fact
```

I think it is working, but I don't really know why the while loop from i to n ... From my lesson I learnt that we have to do if from 2 to sqrt(n).
Did I misunderstand something ?
Can I improve it ?
Thanks :)

Comment: Stopping the loop earlier is an optimization.

Comment: How ?  It looks like if I don't go to n, it doesn't return all the values :/

Comment: N gets smaller every time you find a factor, so you're not actually going up to N's original value.

Comment: If you don't go up to n then you need to add the remaining value of n to the factors at the end.

Comment: @interjay Oh thanks I didn't think about that ! I'll try this one :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fast prime factorization module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643647/fast-prime-factorization-module)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When an integer `n` is not divisible by any number up to `sqrt(n)`, that is sufficient to indicate that `n` is prime. In that case you won't find any additional factors other than `n` itself.

So what you can do is to stop the loop at `sqrt(n)`, and add the remaining value of `n` to the list of prime factors.

Comment: Thanks :) How can I get the remaining value of n at the end of the loop ?

Comment: @Kosmoz Simply `fact.append(n)`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Pollard's rho integer factorization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm). It's quite efficient and fast compared to other algorithms that are much slower. For example:

### Python 3:

```py
from math import gcd

def factorization(n):

    factors = []

    def get_factor(n):
        x_fixed = 2
        cycle_size = 2
        x = 2
        factor = 1

        while factor == 1:
            for count in range(cycle_size):
                if factor > 1: break
                x = (x * x + 1) % n
                factor = gcd(x - x_fixed, n)

            cycle_size *= 2
            x_fixed = x

        return factor

    while n > 1:
        next = get_factor(n)
        factors.append(next)
        n //= next

    return factors
```

With small numbers it's very fast, in this case it has taken only `0.035` seconds.

```py
print(factorization(823767))
```

```sh
~$ time python3 factorization.py
[3, 7, 39227]

real    0m0,035s
user    0m0,031s
sys     0m0,004s
```

If we use slightly larger numbers the calculation time increases, but it's still very fast, in this case just `0.038` seconds.

```py
print(factorization(41612032092))
```

```sh
~$ time python3 factorization.py
[3, 4, 37, 1681, 127, 439]

real    0m0,038s
user    0m0,034s
sys     0m0,004s
```

And if we use very large numbers it takes a little more time, but it's still a very reasonable time considering that it's a huge number. In this case just `28.128` seconds.

```py
print(factorization(23756965471926357236576238546))
```

```sh
~$ time python3 factorization.py
[3, 3, 2, 479, 11423, 582677, 413975744296733]

real    0m28,128s
user    0m28,120s
sys     0m0,008s
```

I hope it helps you. Greetings.

Comment: I really like this, but for me at least `factorization(144)` is returning `[3, 3, 8, 2]` rather than what I need: `[3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]`. Is the incomplete factorization only on 2's or is it unpredictable?

Comment: Looks nice but doesn't handle repeated factors properly - even something as 25 is marked as having no proper factors.

Comment: same for 169 cannot retrieve 13*13

Answer (score -1):

This function with driver

```
def factors(n):
  global tmp
  answ=[]
  tmp=(n)
  addends=[4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6]
  def divn(dvr):
     
    
    global tmp
    while tmp%(dvr)==0:
      answ.append(dvr)
      tmp=tmp//dvr
       
  divn(2)
  divn(3)
  divn(5)
  d=(7)
  while (d)*(d)<=tmp:
     
    for i in range(8):
      divn(d)
      d=d+(addends[i])
  if tmp>1:
    answ.append(tmp)    
  return answ    
     
print(factors(23756965471926357236576238546))
```

found

[2, 3, 3, 479, 11423, 582677, 413975744296733]

in 4 seconds. It does so by skipping over multiples of 2, 3 and 5 after testing those three primes. After testing for those three, it needs test only 8 out of every 30 numbers, starting with 7, in a cycle of addends given in the list of addends to the previously tested number. This cuts down on the number of non-primes used as a test. (30 is 2*3*5, so this constitutes the cycle of multiples of these).

Each tried number is tried as many times as needed until the remaining number is no longer divisible by it.

It uses a function within a function to try the actual division.

Answer (score -1):

An example of using recursive call:

```
def factoring(x, print_eq=True):
    factors = []
    if x == 2:
        factors += [x]
    for i in range(2,x):
        if i*i > x:
            factors += [x]
            break
        if x%i == 0:
            factors += [i]
            factors += factoring(x//i, False)
            break
    # Factorization has been completed.
    # Print the result in pretty mode
    if print_eq:
        if x in factors:
            print(f'{x} = 1 * {x} is a prime')
        else:
            eq = ''
            nf = {i : factors.count(i) for i in factors}
            fs = list(sorted(nf))
            for i, f in enumerate(fs):
                if nf[f] > 1:
                    eq += f'{f}^{nf[f]}'
                else:
                    eq += f'{f}'
                if i < len(fs) - 1:
                    eq += ' * '
            print(f'{x} = {eq}\n')
    return factors
```

Some examples:

factoring(23756965471926357236576238546) gives

23756965471926357236576238546 = 2 * 3^2 * 479 * 11423 * 582677 * 413975744296733

[2, 3, 3, 479, 11423, 582677, 413975744296733]

factoring(1024) gives

1024 = 2^10

[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

factoring(137) gives

137 = 1 * 137 is a prime

[137]

Answer (score -4):

You only need to go to floor(sqrt(n)) if you are looking for smallest factor (such as in a primality test). if you want all the factors then you should check from 0 to n/2.

**In short:**

*primality:*

```
from math import sqrt

n = int(input('Please input a number: '))
sn = int(sqrt(n))
for x in range(2,sn+1):
    if n%x == 0:
        print('Not prime. Divisible by: '+str(x))
print(str(n)+' is prime')
```

*factorization:*

```
n = int(input('Please input a number: '))
n2 = int(n/2)
fn = []
for x in range(2,n2+1):
    if n%x == 0:
        fn.append(x) #lower member of factor pair
        fn.append(n/x) #upper member of factor pair
print('N has the following factors: '+str(fn))
```

I hope this helps you understand.

Comment: OP is doing factorization into primes. Your code prints all the number's factors (primes or not), which is different from factorization.

Comment: As interjay said, that's not really what I'm looking for :/ But you learned me some things, so thanks ! :)

Comment: @interjay At no point in the original post is that mentioned. He is explicity doing a primality test by looking for factors. (and incidentally, the lowest factor of any integer is always a prime.)

Comment: OP's code outputs a prime factorization. And "factorization" does not mean to print all the factors of a number. It means to turn a composite number into a product of separate numbers, so your code is *not* factorization. I look forward to your reply to this comment in another two years.

Comment: And I just noticed that OP himself agreed with me in the comment above, so it's quite bizarre that you're claiming OP's wishes were different.

Comment: Here's the thing, the OP's code only checks to see if `n` is divisible by `i`. To ensure that `i` is a prime factor, `i` either must be pulled from a list of primes, or have it's own primality checked. I can add that to my post within the next two years.

Comment: I suggest you try running OP's code and you will see that it always outputs a prime factorization. `n` will only be divisible by `i` when `i` is prime, for the reason you said above (the smallest factor greater than 1 is always prime).

Comment: Yes, The first number is prime. And while the first number found will be a prime factor, it is not a factorization. A factorization: [Integer Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_Factorization), is a set of all of the factors of a number. A prime factorization is the set of primes which are the factors of a number. For example the number 30, it has the factorization of `(2,15),(3,10),(5,6)`. The prime factorization of 30 is `(2,3,5)`. I think that this is the point about which we disagree in our interpretations of the OP's intent.

Comment: Read the very first line. "In number theory, integer factorization is the decomposition of a composite number into a product of smaller integers. If these integers are further restricted to prime numbers, the process is called prime factorization.". Also, dropping a downvote because you don't like the poster, rather that due to bad code, is classic not not classy.

Comment: I provided code to do `Integer factorization in python` as per the title of the post. The OP's intent may well have been either the first prime factor, or a prime factorization, at the time of my submitting a reply, there was no way to know the OP's intent was different from the question asked.

Comment: As you quoted, "integer factorization is the decomposition of a composite number into a product of smaller integers." True, they don't technically have to be prime (even though that is frequently the assumed implication, and it's what the asker's code does). 24 can, for instance, be factored to 2 and 12, *or* 3 and 8, *or* 4 and 6, etc. Your code, however, lists *all factors*, in this case 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, and 12—not just a set of factors which multiply together into the number in question. Not to mention it lists each of them twice. It's neither what the asker intended, nor technically correct.