# Improve performance on divisor finding function

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, performance

I have made a function that finds all divisors that runs decently fast but for what I am trying to do I want it to run faster. I have also already created a primeFactors function. What I am doing is finding all possible powers that can be made and multiplying them.

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import product

def divisors(n):
    x = sorted(primeFactors(n))
    r = []
    for values in set(x):
        t = list(range(0, x.count(values) + 1))
        r.append(t)
    comb = list(product(*r))
    divisors = []
    for sets in comb:
        n = [a**b for a, b in zip(set(x), sets)]
        divisors.append(reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, n))
    return sorted(divisors)
```

Is there another approach that is faster or any improvements that can be made to this code to make it faster? For the sake of the problem lets assume my primeFactors is the fastest in the world.

Comment: One easy thing to do is change `list(range(...))` to just `range(...)`. The `range` objects can be iterated over directly by `itertools.product`, they don't get "used up" the first time you iterate over them. Likewise, you don't need to do `list(product(*r))`, just iterate over `product(*r)` directly.

Comment: İf you can give your ``primeFactors`` funtion to us , we can try and edit your code.

Comment: I would but that would be annoying because I use rho-brent and isPrime and I have additional code for that and in those, I use other functions that would just make this post unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I use something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643647/fast-prime-factorization-module guy's prime factors method with a few edits to make it slightly faster.

Comment: In cases where it's too slow, how much time is spent in `primeFactors` and how much time is spent in the rest?

Comment: Usually, primeFactors takes up the most time but I want to make this function itself faster. But to give you an example, for the number `123455931812973491283740912393842093480293` takes up `1.305483102798462` seconds for the primeFactors and the divisors function besides that takes up `0.0006866455` seconds.

Comment: Wait not `1.305483102798462` it actually took `0.5246880054473877` seconds go the wrong test.

Comment: It's not Python, but you might look at `ComputeAllFactors` (which calls `PermuteFactors`) in http://myfactors.mooo.com/source/cyclop.cpp - but note that it's kind of weird in explicitly skipping the trivial factors and then conditionally re-adding them at the end (because that was added after).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a lot of ways to make small efficiency gains in your function:

- There is no need to sort the list of prime factors. This doesn't have any effect on your algorithm.
- You are converting the list of factors to a set many times, including within a loop; just do it once.
- You are using `.count` to count each factor separately; the `.count` method loops over the list each time it's called. You can count occurrences of all factors in one pass using a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).
- List comprehensions are usually a tiny bit faster than calling `append` in a loop.
- The `range` objects and the `product` generator don't need to be converted to lists.
- You are computing `a**b` many times for each `b` in the range for the factor `a`; you could take the product over a list of `a**b` instead of just the range for `b`.
- Using `reduce` with `operator.mul` is faster than with a lambda.
- The `.sort` method should be a little bit faster than `sorted`.

Some of these improvements involve removing or changing enough of the code that the other improvements are moot. Here's the resulting code:

```py
from functools import reduce
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter
from operator import mul

def divisors2(n):
    factors = primeFactors(n)
    r = [
        [ a ** b for b in range(t + 1) ]
        for a, t in Counter(factors).items()
    ]
    d = [ reduce(mul, sets) for sets in product(*r) ]
    d.sort()
    return d
```

Overall this gives a modest to large improvement in running time, depending on the number of divisors:

- For `1234567891` which is a prime number, the time saved is about 1%.
- For `1234567890 == 2 * 3 * 3 * 5 * 3607 * 3803` the time saved is about 10%.
- For `3333960000 == 2**6 * 3**5 * 5**4 * 7**3` the time saved is about 75%.

To do a bit better, we can save multiplying the same numbers over and over in the `reduce` stage by redesigning the implementation to use a recursive function instead of `itertools.product`: this allows us to do fewer multiplications overall.

```py
def divisors3(n):
    factors = primeFactors(n)
    factor_counts = list(Counter(factors).items())

    def helper(x, i):
        if i < 0:
            d.append(x)
        else:
            a, t = factor_counts[i]
            for b in range(t + 1):
                helper(x, i - 1)
                x *= a

    d = []
    helper(1, len(factor_counts) - 1)
    d.sort()
    return d
```

This improves the time saved from 75% to 80% for the number with many prime factors. The difference for the other test cases is too small to matter.

---

I compared all three functions using the following fairly basic `primeFactors` implementation (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22808285/12299000)):

```py
def primeFactors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for. If you don't mind me asking do you know any faster methods for calculating divisors from primeFactors? I just made mine because I wanted to see if I could do it somewhat fast Thanks!

Comment: The technique you used, of taking the Cartesian product over the different powers of each prime factor, should be about optimal. In principle the implementation can be significantly redesigned, so that it uses a recursive function instead of `itertools.product` to avoid multiplying the same numbers over and over, but the saving is not big; I'll edit to include this version.

Comment: Since you're already benchmarking and I don't know how you do, could you try this one as well? https://repl.it/repls/DecimalLastPerl

Comment: @StefanPochmann nice one; your solution is about twice as fast as `divisors3` for the number with lots of factors. I suggest posting it as an answer; it's not obvious to me how your algorithm works so it would be useful to give some explanation. (I think you're relying on equal factors being adjacent in the list?) By the way, I'm just using `timeit.timeit(lambda: divisors(n), number=10000)` to benchmark them.

Answer (score 1):

Almost three times as fast as @kaya3's solutions and about 13 times as fast as your original (on kaya3's example number 3333960000):

```
def divisors(n):
    divisors = [1]
    for p in primeFactors(n):
        if divisors[-1] % p:
            divs = divisors
        divs = [d * p for d in divs]
        divisors += divs
    return sorted(divisors)
```

For example if the prime factors are `[2, 2, 2, 3, 3]`, then you can multiply the initial `1` with the prime factor `2` up to three times, giving you the divisors `[1, 2, 4, 8]`. All of which you can then multiply with prime factor `3` up to two times. Multiplying with it once gives you `[3, 6, 12, 24]` and multiplying with it twice you `[9, 18, 36, 72]`. These additional divisor lists are my `divs`. At each new prime factor, I set `divs` to the `divisors` producible by the previous prime factors, and then keep multiplying it with the current prime factor and adding to the overall result.

This needs equal prime factors to appear consecutively, which is highly likely (once the factorization finds a prime factor, it likely extracts it completely so that the remaining factorization is faster). If that's not the case, just use `sorted(primeFactors(n))`.

[Benchmark](https://repl.it/repls/UnpleasantGoldCompilerbug) results (times in seconds for 10,000 calls with n=3333960000):

```
 0.22 primeFactors
95.43 divisors_aayush
15.28 divisors_kaya3_1
17.91 divisors_kaya3_2
 5.40 divisors_stefan

 0.21 primeFactors
89.29 divisors_aayush
17.91 divisors_kaya3_1
18.79 divisors_kaya3_2
 6.81 divisors_stefan

 0.20 primeFactors
94.21 divisors_aayush
21.28 divisors_kaya3_1
22.48 divisors_kaya3_2
 7.36 divisors_stefan
```

Btw, just in case the result doesn't really have to be sorted: Without sorting the result it takes about 2.4 seconds. So that sorting is responsible for most of the time.

Comment: Excellent solution and explanation! Is it correct to say that `divisors` is the list of all divisors so far, and `divs` is the list of only those divisors with the same multiplicity of the current prime factor?

Comment: Wow wow wow. With your method divisors ran in about 1.3 seconds for 10000 iterations of 3333960000. Thank you

Comment: This was about 100 times faster for the number `195643523275200`. That's really smart.