# Prime factors for a large number (150-bit number)

Tags: python, prime-factoring, largenumber, factorization

I have a really large number `510143758735509025530880200653196460532653147` from which I want to obtain its prime factors (or at least the two biggest factors) in python. I have tried with several codes but they run for ages and they don't finish. So I'm asking, is there any fast way or at least a way to compute the prime factors of a number this big?

PS: for example, one of the codes I used.

```
def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors
```

Comment: @khelwood that's wrong, there are faster ways to do it, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31986424/791430

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll take a look at it!

Comment: Okay, I found a page at the end: http://factordb.com/index.php?query=742449129124467073921545687640895127535705902454369756401331

Comment: @khelwood using the msieve software I got: `19704762736204164635843 * 25889363174021185185929 = 510143758735509025530880200653196460532653147` instantly

Comment: Thank you, yes that was what I was looking for! :)

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: I have a python library that you can use to factor these numbers in ipython3. It uses Alpertons ECM SIQS engine: https://github.com/oppressionslayer/primalitytest it even works under termux on android

Comment: Thank you too, I'll take a look! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used PariDroid on my cell phone; it completed the factorization in an instantL

```
factor(510143758735509025530880200653196460532653147) =
19704762736204164635843 * 25889363174021185185929
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way using this webpage, just if someone needs it.
http://factordb.com/index.php?query=742449129124467073921545687640895127535705902454369756401331