# All possible pairs of factors

Tags: python, math

I am trying to write a program that takes a number with a single leading integer and an arbitrary number of trailing zeros and then prints all possible combinations of two factors.

ie.

100

factors are 2^2, 5^2

so the program would print:

(2,50),(4,25),(5,20)

or

600

factors are 2^3,3,5^2

(2,300),(4,150),(8,75),(3,200),(5,120),(25,24),(6,100),(12,50),(15,40),(30,20),(60,10)

...I think that's all of them?  Is it?  I could use a program to check...

```
import itertools

facts=[[2,2,2],[3],[5,5]]
for n in itertools.product(*facts)
    print(n)
```

I see that I am using this incorrectly but that was my first stab at it.

This just gives (2,3,5) ten times.

I want something like (2) * (2,3,5,5) and (2,2) * (3,5.5) and the like...

Comment: Do you have any code from what you've tried?

Comment: Sure, but it's trash, that's why I came here..?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.com. To show effort, posters are expected to at least show some code that they have tried, or links to research they have done. Just a formality here on SO.

Comment: @PrincePeregrine: If you don't post your existing code, people will automatically assume that your are trying to cheat at homework and will harass you and close your question within a matter of minutes.

Comment: @Blender not true. What I've seen is that if you don't post your code, people will *ignore* the question and simply not bother to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[To generate all factors of a number given its prime factors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1010460/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import itertools, operator

def all_factors(prime_dict):
    series = [[p**e for e in range(maxe+1)] for p, maxe in prime_dict.items()]
    for multipliers in itertools.product(*series):
        yield reduce(operator.mul, multipliers)
```

#### Example

```
prime_dict = {2:3, 3:1, 5:2}
L = sorted(all_factors(prime_dict))
number_of_divisors = reduce(lambda prod, e: prod*(e+1), prime_dict.values(),1)
assert len(L) == number_of_divisors
# -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 24,
#     25, 30, 40, 50, 60, 75, 100, 120, 150, 200, 300, 600]
```

To produce pairs:

```
n, isodd = divmod(len(L), 2)
print(zip(L[:n], reversed(L[n + isodd:])))
if isodd: # number is perfect square
   print((L[n], L[n]))
```

#### Output

```
[(1, 600), (2, 300), (3, 200), (4, 150), (5, 120), (6, 100),
 (8, 75), (10, 60), (12, 50), (15, 40), (20, 30), (24, 25)]
```

It works for small numbers. You could use it to test your solution that could take into account the special form of your numbers: `x00000...`

Comment: Having trouble dissecting exactly what you did.  Can you explain the 'p**e' and 'p,' parts of your for loops?

Comment: O!, it's like 'piping' for loops..?  Very cool.  What's the terminology used to describe a move like that?

Comment: Easily handles something like 300000000000000000000 {2:20,3:1,5:20} which would cripple a method that finds the factors first using range().

Comment: @PrincePeregrine: number of divisors in `N = 3*10**20` is only `21*21*2`. The above method has O(log(N)**2 *log(log(N))) time complexity for your case (I assume number of divisors is  `~log(N)**2`). If you double number of digits in `N` the amount of work increases more than 4 times.

Comment: @PrincePeregrine: the part with `p**e` produces series of all prime powers that can be in a factor of the number. They may occurs in a factor exactly once due to each multiplier is a power of single prime factor. Cartesian product of these series produces all possible factors.

Comment: @PrincePeregrine: the term for the function that does the loop "piping" is generator (if you mean the part in the code with the `yield` statement) i.e., `all_factors` is a [generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it:

```
def factors(n):
  # Fill this in

def factor_pairs(n):
  for i in factors(n):  # You need to write the factor() function
    yield i, n / i

if __name__ == '__main__':
  n = input('Enter an integer: ')

  for i, j in factor_pairs(n):
    print i, j
```

I'm not going to code it for you entirely, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks the factoring part I have down it was the all possible combinations thing that was tripping me up.  When I factor it though it lists the factors as 2**w, 3**x, 5**y, 7**z.  For yours to work I'd have to iterate all of the possible factors, and list it that way, and that is exactly what I am having trouble doing.

Comment: Just see which numbers divide `n`. You don't really need prime factorization of a number to list factor pairs, do you?

Comment: No, but I thought it would be the most efficient for large numbers since each number I am finding the pairs for only uses 2s and 5s, and every so often 3s, and 7s.

Comment: What do you mean by that? What's an example number?

Comment: So how will your method work for numbers like `5723`? That number has only two distinct prime factors, namely `59` and `97`.

Comment: It needn't work for a number like that.  I stipulated in the question that the number has a single leading integer, and an arbitrary number of trailing 0s.  ie 700, 10000, 50000, 600000, 90, 3000000000000000000000000 et al

Answer (score 1):

You can put it all in a list comprehension

```
import math
n = 600 # or whatever...
[(x, n/x) for x in range(1, int(math.sqrt(n))+1) if n % x == 0]
```

Returns:

```
[(1, 600), (2, 300), (3, 200), (4, 150), (5, 120), (6, 100), (8, 75), (10, 60), (12, 50), (15, 40), (20, 30), (24, 25)]
```

If you don't want (1,600) just use range(2, int(math.sqrt(n))+1).

Comment: This is great, but it steps one integer at a time, which can be costly for a large number.  Since I know the numbers are a combination of 2s and 5s, and sometimes 3s, and 7s, I was looking for a solution that just shows possible combinations of these values.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do what you want:

```
n = input('Enter a number? ')
factors = []

for i in range(int(sqrt(n))):
  if n % i == 0:
    factors.append((i, n / i))
```

By the definition of factors, the maximum number you have to check is up to the square root of the number, so if you can code this, you should be set.

If you can code this, you should be set.

Comment: Thanks to @Blender for the syntax.