# Print unique factors of a number in python

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I have the below code which prints the unique combination of factors of a given number.
But I does not give the desired output. The code is a s follows:

```
#Print the factors list for the given number
def print_factors_list(dividend, factorstring, predivisor):
"""This function takes a number and prints the factors"""
divisor = dividend - 1
for i in range(divisor, 1, -1 ):
    if dividend % i != 0:
        continue

    if i > predivisor:
        continue

    quotient = dividend / i


    if quotient <= i:
        if quotient <= predivisor:
            print factorstring + str(i) + "*" + str(quotient)
    print_factors_list(quotient, str(factorstring) + str(i) + "*", i)
    #Check if the number is greater than 0
    def print_factors(x):
    # Check if the number is greater than 0 
    if (x < 0):
       print "Enter a positive interger"
    #Go to the function print_factors_list for further evaluation
    else:
    print_factors_list(x, str(x) + "*" + str(1) + "\n", x )

    #Take input from the user
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    print_factors(num)
```

I am getting output as follows:

```
32*1
16*2
32*1
8*4
32*1
8*2*2
32*1
4*4*2
32*1
4*2*2*2
32*1
2*2*2*2*2
```

I should get

```
 32*1
 16*2
 8*4
 8*2*2
 4*4*2
 4*2*2*2
 2*2*2*2*2
```

I am anewbie in python so making some silly mistake. Please can someone help where in the logic I am going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Double check your code formatting.  Markdown has messed up your indentation, which kills any Python code.

Comment: The code cannot be run; please fix the indentation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need all possible factors of a number or just the prime factorization?

If the former, you should be able to construct it comfortably from the latter. I heartily encourage using sympy, the symbolic math library for python.

```
from sympy import *
primefactors(5551) #provides which primes are included
[7, 13, 61]
factorint(5551) #provides how often each prime occurs
{7: 1, 13: 1, 61: 1}
```

Then it's just a combinatorial problem from there.

Also, see [Python factorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010381/python-factorization?rq=1)

Here's what it would look like with three constituent primes to get all possible factors

```
prime=6329487
pl=primefactors(prime)
pp=factorint(prime)
for i in xrange(1+pp[pl[0]]):
    for j in xrange(1+pp[pl[1]]):
        for k in xrange(1+pp[pl[2]]):
            print (pl[0]**i)*(pl[1]**j)*(pl[2]**k)
```

Comment: I am interested in possible factors

Comment: I discuss the problem of finding the prime partitions of a number at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/10/19/prime-partitions/). The basic method uses dynamic programming. If the primes less than the target _n_ are _a_, _b_, ..., _z_, then the prime partitions of _n_ are the prime partitions of _n_ - _a_ with _a_ added, plus the prime partitions of _n_ - _b_ with _b_ added, plus ..., plus the prime partitions of _n_ - _z_ with _z_ added. Dynamic programming first finds the prime partitions of 2, then 3, then 4, and so on, all the way up to _n_.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to this as follows. I was loking for all the factors combination but not the unique ones. Thank you.

```
#Python program to print out all ways to multiply smaller integers 
#that equal the original number, without repeating sets of factors



def print_factors_list(dividend, factorstring, predivisor):
"""This function takes a number and prints the factors"""


   divisor = dividend - 1
   #Looping to get the factors
   for i in range(divisor, 1, -1 ):

        if dividend % i != 0:
        continue

        if i > predivisor:
        continue
        #Get the quotient for the multipying number   
        quotient = dividend / i


        if quotient <= i:
           if quotient <= predivisor:
           print factorstring + str(i) + "*" + str(quotient)
        print_factors_list(quotient, str(factorstring) + str(i) + "*", i)




#Check if the number is greater than 0
def print_factors(x):
# Check if the number is greater than 0 
    if (x < 0):
       print "Enter a positive integer"
    #Check if the number is 0
    elif (x == 0):
        print "Enter a positive integer"
    #Go to the function print_factors_list for further evaluation
    else:
    #Print the default factors(the number itself and 1)
       print str(x) + "*" + str(1)
    print_factors_list(x, "", x )




#Take input from the user
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
#Call the function with the number given by the user
print_factors(num)
```

Comment: This faults with "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'quotient' referenced before assignment" for the first "random" number I fed it: 1729

Comment: @msw - Indentation might not be correct. But the logic works fine for me.