# fastest way to produce a list of all divisors of a number

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

Given a number `n`, I want to generate a sorted list of all the unique divisors of `n` (with no duplications).
Solving this problem is really straight forward, but what I'm interested in is the efficiency.
What is the fastest way to do it?

Here is one way, with pure python:

```py
def get_divisors(n):
    """
    :param n: positive integer.
    :return: list of all different divisors of n.
    """
    if n <= 0:
        return []
    divisors = [1, n]
    for div in range(1, int(n ** 0.5 + 1)):
        if n % div == 0:
            divisors.extend([n // div, div])
    return sorted(list(set(divisors)))
```

Any suggestions on how to optimize this?
Numpy and other optimized libraries are welcome.

Comment: Just for clarity, you're already using the square root trick for divisors to cut down your search where you won't get any unique pair of divisors for a number n after sqrt(n), right?

Comment: yes, looking for other mathematical or pythonic optimizations

Comment: sympy has a nice number theory [module for factoring](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html?highlight=divisors#sympy.ntheory.factor_.divisors) that's quite a bit faster on large numbers. The docs reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010381/python-factorization) for prime factors.

Comment: If you numbers are small, then precompute a list of prime divisors. If your numbers are big (eg. >1_000_000), then you need a much more clever algorithm. For example you can use the Fermat's factorization if the numbers are not too huge (eg. < 1G). For huge numbers, this problem is very hard to solve efficiently (this is an open math problem). So: how big are your numbers?

Comment: @JérômeRichard under 1G

Comment: It turns out that the Fermat's factorization is very slow compared to the Wheel factorization for random integers close to 1G. The Pollard Rho factorization is supposed to be fast for fairly big numbers (1e9 to 1e15) but in practice it is also slower than it (but much faster than the Fermat's factorization).

Answer (score 3):

Since the input is assumed not to be bigger than 1 billion, you can **compute the prime factors using a [Wheel factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization)** (with the basis `{2, 3}`) which is an improvement of the basic trial division. This is fast because the number of prime factors is always small (no more than 30 values). You can then transform the prime factors to the list of divisor (with possibly thousands of items). The factorization can be computed efficiently using the **Numba just-in-time compiler** (JIT). Here is the resulting code:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('List(int_)(int_)')
def get_prime_divisors(n):
    divisors = []
    while n % 2 == 0:
        divisors.append(2)
        n //= 2
    while n % 3 == 0:
        divisors.append(3)
        n //= 3
    i = 5
    while i*i <= n:
        for k in (i, i+2):
            while n % k == 0:
                divisors.append(k)
                n //= k
        i += 6
    if n > 1:
        divisors.append(n)
    return divisors

@nb.njit('List(int_)(int_)')
def get_divisors(n):
    divisors = []
    if n == 1:
        divisors.append(1)
    elif n > 1:
        prime_factors = get_prime_divisors(n)
        divisors = [1]
        last_prime = 0
        factor = 0
        slice_len = 0
        # Find all the products that are divisors of n
        for prime in prime_factors:
            if last_prime != prime:
                slice_len = len(divisors)
                factor = prime
            else:
                factor *= prime
            for i in range(slice_len):
                divisors.append(divisors[i] * factor)
            last_prime = prime
        divisors.sort()
    return divisors
```

Here are timings on my machine for 5000 random integers between 1 and 1 million:

```
Initial get_divisors:        125 ms
Alain's getDivs:              40 ms
Tim Peters' get_divisors:     87 ms
This solution:                 7 ms
```

Here are timings on my machine for 2000 random integers between 1 and 1 billion:

```
Initial get_divisors:       1403 ms
Alain's getDivs:             231 ms
Tim Peters' get_divisors:    178 ms
This solution:                 8 ms
```

Thus, this solution is up to 6~22 times faster than the fastest alternative solution and **up to 18~175 times faster than the initial implementation**.

Comment: great one. I don't know how numba works but the int_ failed it, changed to int64 and it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You already have the square root optimization.  Next would be to leverage numpy's parallelism:

```
import numpy as np

def npDivs(N):
    divs = np.arange(1,int(N**0.5)+1)  # potential divisors up to √N
    divs = divs[N % divs==0]           # divisors
    comp = N//divs[::-1]               # complement quotients
    return np.concatenate((divs,comp[divs[-1]==comp[0]:])) # combined
    
print(getDivs(1001**2))
[      1       7      11      13      49      77      91     121     143
     169     539     637     847    1001    1183    1573    1859    5929
    7007    8281   11011   13013   20449   77077   91091  143143 1002001]
```

`comp[divs[-1]==comp[0]:]` avoids repeating the square root if it is an integer.

An even faster approach, would be to get prime factors and combine them in a resulting set:

```
def getDivs(N):
    factors = {1}
    maxP  = int(N**0.5)
    p,inc = 2,1
    while p <= maxP:
        while N%p==0:
            factors.update([f*p for f in factors])
            N //= p
            maxP = int(N**0.5)
        p,inc = p+inc,2
    if N>1:
        factors.update([f*N for f in factors])
    return sorted(factors)
```

Benchmarks:

```
from timeit import timeit
N = 1010101**2
print(timeit(lambda:getDivs(N),number=100))      # 0.0015
print(timeit(lambda:npDivs(N),number=100))       # 0.9753
print(timeit(lambda:get_divisors(N),number=100)) # 8.5605
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect the fastest way is to build the divisors "ground up" from a full prime factorization of the input. But you're not going to get an answer here for "the fastest way" to get a prime factorization to begin with: that's a huge topic all on its own, and still a very active area of research for large integers.

The way below simply uses trial division, up through the square root of what remains to be factored, but skipping multiples of 2 and 3 (except for 2 and 3 themselves). This is reasonably zippy through 32-bit ints.

Given a prime factorization

```
n == p0**e0 * p1**e1 * p2**e2 ...
```

Then the divisors of `n` are all and only the integers of that form with exponents less than or equal equal to the `e0, e1, e2, ...`. `itertools.product()` can straightforwardly generate all such tuples of exponents, and then it's just a matter of doing the powers and multiplying the results.

```
def get_divisors(n):
    from math import isqrt, prod
    from itertools import accumulate, chain, cycle, product
    if n <= 1:
        return [n]
    ps = []
    exps = []
    limit = isqrt(n)
    for cand in chain([2, 3], accumulate(cycle([2, 4]),
                                               initial=5)):
        if cand > limit:
            break
        if n % cand == 0:
            count = 1
            n //= cand
            while n % cand == 0:
                count += 1
                n //= cand
            ps.append(cand)
            exps.append(count)
            limit = isqrt(n)
    if n > 1:
        ps.append(n)
        exps.append(1)
    result = []
    for pows in product(*(range(exp + 1) for exp in exps)):
        result.append(prod(p**e for p, e in zip(ps, pows)))
    return sorted(result)

>>> for i in range(22):
...     print(i, get_divisors(i))
0 [0]
1 [1]
2 [1, 2]
3 [1, 3]
4 [1, 2, 4]
5 [1, 5]
6 [1, 2, 3, 6]
7 [1, 7]
8 [1, 2, 4, 8]
9 [1, 3, 9]
10 [1, 2, 5, 10]
11 [1, 11]
12 [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]
13 [1, 13]
14 [1, 2, 7, 14]
15 [1, 3, 5, 15]
16 [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
17 [1, 17]
18 [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18]
19 [1, 19]
20 [1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20]
21 [1, 3, 7, 21]
```